# How to go directly into a row in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have a huge sqlite database with 800,000 rows and it takes a long time if the row is near the end like `select * from tbl where id=578511`. This is because the query runs from the beginning of the database, but is it possible to go just directly to that row as the id equals the rowcount.

Comment: Do you have an index on `id`?

Answer (score 2):

Make id a primary key. It should help.

Comment: I just changed the structure of the table by making id the primary key. Now there is no lag in time when querying a row near the end of the table, great.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to add the index of the table to make the query faster:

```
 CREATE INDEX tbl_id ON tbl(id);
```

or if the data is frequently read, you can also keep them in memory.